# I want to know how to use -> in php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I sometimes see this kind of thing`$this->something->function_name()` in php and I dont know what does this `->` really mean. Can somebody clear me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reference to the current object, it's most commonly used in object oriented code.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Primer:http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html

Example:

```
<?php
class Person {
    public $name;

    function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
};

$Ntiyiso = new Person('Ntiyiso Trumind Rikhotso');
echo $Ntiyiso->name;
```

This stores the 'Ntiyiso' string as a property of the object created.